# how to access hidden field value from asp.net to javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebPages.WebForm1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="test" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById('<%= test.ClientID%>').value
 }
 </script>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I unable to get value from code behind file to java script code by using dot value but the dot value is unidentified in code.i try many different solution but nothing work.

Comment: If you are setting your control to Visible=False from the code behind it will not be rendered to the client and javascript can never interact with it. In that case you need to use a class to set the display or rethink what you are trying to do.

Comment: I set the visibility true but still .value is unidentified in Visual Studio. I am just trying to access some variable of asp.net web page in javascript code.I am working on google map and need some variable from asp.net to javascript.

Comment: Where are you calling `myFunction` in javascript? order matters because if you call it before the textbox has rendered it wont exist. Beyond that you may want to read up on client side vs server side. They cannot easily interact because they serve different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using a textbox to read from as a hiddenvalue field use.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
```

and read with

```
var myValue = document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>').value;
```

And what Marie said if any control has visible="false" it will not be rendered to client so its never available to read from on clientside.

Also your function `myFunction` does nothing with the value what exactly are you trying to do with the value